# Mac OS X (El Capitan): Putting Java application name on the menu bar

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea

When you run a Java application on `Mac OS X`, the main class name is displayed in the menu bar by default.

1. I've seen the solution of setting a system property [here](https://alvinalexander.com/java/java-application-name-mac-menu-bar-menubar-class-name) but it doesn't work at all.
2. Furthermore, I tried setting the `Xdock` command line property `name` which worked but I'm not entirely happy with it. I want to be able to set the text on runtime due to different languages.
3. A 3rd approach I've seen is [writing a specific Ant script for Mac OS X](https://alvinalexander.com/java/mac-os-x-java-ant-build-script-jarbundler-native) but I don't want to do that for such a simple task. The application needs to run on all platforms and not just `Mac OS X`. I'm using `Maven` as build system and `IntelliJ IDEA` as `IDE`.

The folder structure is:

```
my-project
-src
--main
---java
---resources
```

Any solution **on runtime** which still works for `Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.6` (and newer)?